# DBSCAN clustering - epsilon

Tags: python, clustering, scikit-learn, dbscan

How do we decide on the optimum epsilon and min_samples to be specified given our data? Take this for example - Demo of DBSCAN clustering algorithm via https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X)
```

According to https://www.kaggle.com/code/pnarerdoan/k-means-dbscan-clustering/notebook that the optimum number of clusters is calculated based on the highest Silhouette score by looping through a range of both eps and min_samples values.

https://machinelearningknowledge.ai/tutorial-for-dbscan-clustering-in-python-sklearn/#iii_Types_of_Points_in_DBSCAN_Clustering uses k nearest neighbors as a starting input to get the optimum epsilon. If so, how do we decide what is the right k nearest neighbors to start with given our data?

Comment: You define these hyperparameters based on domain knowledge. A clustering by itself is useless. It is only relevant if it can allow insights that are applicable to an otherwise unstructured dataset. Indeed the highest Silhouette score for different numbers of clusters is a way to pick a "best" clustering but that doesn't mean it is the most informative for you (and obviously it impossible to quantify how much better a score of 0.65 is from a score of 0.625).